# Showing a function to be a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

I want to prove or disprove that $\parallel (x,y)\parallel=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}}$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Since $\{(x,y):\parallel(x,y)\parallel\leq1\}$ is a convex set,  $\parallel\cdot\parallel$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^2$. But I could not show the triangle inequality explicitly. Though I know that the above condition is equivalent to the triangle inequality, still I want to prove that. Please provide any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm and $A$ is invertible, then $n(x) = \|Ax\|$ is also a norm.

In your case, $Ax = ({1 \over 3} x_1, {1 \over 2 }x_2)^T$.

The triangle inequality follows from the original norm as in:
$n(x+y) = \|A(x+y)\| = \|Ax+Ay\| \le \|Ax\|+\|Ay\| = n(x)+n(y)$.

The other conditions follow as well: $n( \lambda x) = \|A (\lambda x)\| = |\lambda \|Ax\| = |\lambda| n(x)$. We have $n(x) \ge 0$ since $\|y\| \ge 0$ for all $y$. Finally, $n(x)=0$ **iff** $\|Ax\|=0$ **iff** $Ax = 0$ **iff** $x = 0$ (since $A$ is invertible).